# how can i read an element except specific child element?

Tags: jquery

sorry for bad english.
i want to read element with "a" id but  no "b" element in result?

```
<div id="a">
hi
<div id="b">
every one
</div>
<div>bye</div>
</div>
```

and result should be

```
 hi <div>bye</div>
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want an HTML string as the result.

You could make a `.clone()` of `#a`, remove the `#b` from the clone, then get the `.html()` content.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uZ97k/

```
var html = $('#a').clone().children().remove('#b').end().html();
```

or it could be written like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uZ97k/1/

```
var html = $('#a').clone().children('#b').remove().end().html();
```

Comment: Here is a demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/6zW36/. Edit: I see the post has been updated with demos.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the jQuery [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector method will work well for you.

**Edit**: Please note that I interpreted your question literally. This will select elements that do **not** match a certain property. If you were making a generalization with your example code, then this might not work for what you wish. It might be helpful if you could clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap "hi" in a div tag like this

```
<div id="a">
  **<div> hi </div>**
<div id="b">
every one
</div>
<div>bye</div>
</div>
```

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var result = $("#a").children(":not(#b)").html();
</script>
```